# jquery slide: which one?

Tags: jquery, slide

Does anyone know what kind of slide function that [this website](http://www.studio-output.com/) is using?

I tried with `slideToggle` but it is not the same.

```
$('div').slideToggle('fast');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
/*
Title:      jQuery.slideshow
Description:Fading slideshow widget
Developer:  Antenna Praxis (http://theantenna.org)
Released:   June 2009
Updated:    Feb 2010
Version:    0.0.5
Usage:      $('container-elem').slideshow(options).slideshow('start');
Notes:      
            - Pauses to load unloaded img
            - Pauses on rollover (resumes on rollout)
            - Crossfade if old+new img dimensions are the same, otherwise fade out->in     instead
            - Constrains img WH to max dimensions
To Do:      
License:    Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses:
            http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php,
            http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*/
```

Believe me, that's the first time I reproduce a license without prducing the code :-D